# How to merge nodes of the same community with Cypher in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, graph-data-science

There is a graph, each of its nodes contains property `communityId` to indicate which community the node belongs to. The nodes are connected with `LINK` relationship, which contains `weight` property.

What I want is to merge those nodes of the same community into a big node. The links between those big nodes (aka. communities) must be synthesized/combined **reasonably**: the `weight` property of the link must be added up, based on individual nodes in each community connected to the other. Direction of the link must be respected.

In the result graph, I will only see connected *community* nodes.

The closest function is [Merge Nodes](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/), function `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes()`. However, I'm dissatisfied with the result because:

- Problem 1: The result community nodes have self-link.
- Problem 2: Weights of the links are not combined although the documentation says so.

Problem 1 can be fixed by writing one more Cypher to remove self-links. But problem 2 can only be tackled with low-level access to the Graph (like `mergeNodes()` above).

Is there any elegant approach to have my desired graph (*community* nodes) in **one go**? Or at least, problem 2 must be fixed somehow.

### Reproducibility

Graph:

```
CREATE (a:User {name: "A", communityId: 2}), (b:User {name: "B", communityId: 2}), (c:User {name: "C", communityId: 2}), (x:User {name: "X", communityId: 1}), (y:User {name: "Y", communityId: 1}), (z:User {name: "Z", communityId: 1}), (w:User {name: "W", communityId: 1}), (a)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(b), (b)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(c), (c)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(a), (b)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(z), (z)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(x), (z)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(w), (w)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(y), (y)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(x), (b)-[:LINK {weight: 1}]->(w)
```

[image]

Cypher:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WITH n.communityId AS communityId, COLLECT(n) AS nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {
    properties: {
        name: 'combine',
        communityId: 'discard',
        weight: 'combine'
    },
    mergeRels: true
})
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

[image]

### System Requirement

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Neo4j Desktop v1.3.4 (Engine v4.1.1.)
- APOC v4.1.0.2
- Graph Data Science Library v1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why APOC is not merging the relationships in your example. However, here is a Cypher query to get you started:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r]->(v:User)
WHERE n.communityId <> v.communityId  // discard self loop
WITH n.communityId as comId1, v.communityId as comId2, sum(r.weight) as w
MERGE (su1:SuperUser {communityId: comId1})  // create or get merged node for n.communityId
MERGE (su2:SuperUser {communityId: comId2})  // create or get node for v.communityId
MERGE (su1)-[r:SUPER_LINK]->(su2)
ON CREATE SET r.weight = w  // set relationship weight when it is created
RETURN su1, su2, r
```

which creates the following nodes and relationship:

[image: Super node and super link]

Comment: Thanks. That's a good starting point. Although the Cypher doesn't delete the original graph, I guess I can additionally just execute `MATCH (n) WHERE NOT n:SuperUser DETACH DELETE n`.